# Error given when trying to use Sytem.Text.Json

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, replit

When I try to include the namespace System.Text.Json, I am given the following error:

The type or namespace called 'JSON' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I need this for serializing objects and I am currently using Repl.it on a Chromebook. Have I done something wrong and if not, is there some other way of solving this?

**I can not upload an entire folder (limitations when using Repl.it) so solutions like json.net will likely not work.**

Comment: could you please include the relevant pieces of ***code***? otherwise - how do you expect us to take a look at your code and tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Text.Json is new namespace, you need to install it as Nuget package.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to use Visual Studio on my PC then.